# realloc: invalid next size error

Tags: c, realloc

I am having this error with `realloc` that only occurs on my school's lab computer and not on mine.

In this program, I am storing line numbers in a `File_Node` struct. `File_Node` is part of a linked list and each node contains a file path string and an array line numbers in the file.

This program works fine until there are too many line numbers (> 3000) which need to be stored.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
           if ((token = strtok(NULL, delim)) != NULL) {
                    char *endptr = NULL;
                    int *linenum_tmp = NULL;
                    long line_number;
                    errno = 0;
                    line_number = strtol(token, &endptr, 10);

                    if (errno == ERANGE) {
                            exit_program("Integer overflow.");
                    }

                    if (*endptr != '\0' || endptr == token || line_number < 0) {
                            exit_program("Cannot parse line number input.");
                    }
                    if (tail->line_numbers == NULL) {
                            tail->line_numbers = malloc(num_array_sz * sizeof(int));
                    }
                    if (counter == num_array_sz) { //Area of interest
                            num_array_sz *= 2;
                            if ((linenum_tmp = realloc(tail->line_numbers, sizeof(int) * num_array_sz)) == NULL) { 
                                    exit_program("Error in realloc."); 
                            }
                    }
                    *(tail->line_numbers + counter - 1) = line_number;

            } else {
                    exit_program("Cannot parse line number input.");
            }
            counter++;
```

The code above is part of a bigger while loop which contains a lot more lines, but I will post it if necessary. This is why there is a `counter++` at the bottom. I basically double the size of `num_array_sz` everytime the `counter`, which represents the number of lines stored, reaches `num_array_sz`, which is initialized as `256`.

On my own computer, I tested this with way more input than the school's computer and it worked flawlessly.

I curious if this is due to limited ram on my school's computer or possibly a difference in platform.

Here is the valgrind output I ran on the school's computer:

```
==1579== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1579== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1579== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1579== Command: ./rgpp_v2 -w the -b -n
==1579== 
==1579== Invalid write of size 4
==1579==    at 0x40110E: process_input (rgpp_v2.c:181)
==1579==    by 0x400DCC: main (rgpp_v2.c:103)
==1579==  Address 0x51e0b9c is 1,020 bytes inside a block of size 1,024 free'd
==1579==    at 0x4C29B7E: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1579==    by 0x4010DD: process_input (rgpp_v2.c:177)
==1579==    by 0x400DCC: main (rgpp_v2.c:103)
==1579== 
==1579== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==1579==    at 0x4C29B7E: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1579==    by 0x4010DD: process_input (rgpp_v2.c:177)
==1579==    by 0x400DCC: main (rgpp_v2.c:103)
==1579==  Address 0x51e07a0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1,024 free'd
==1579==    at 0x4C29B7E: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1579==    by 0x4010DD: process_input (rgpp_v2.c:177)
==1579==    by 0x400DCC: main (rgpp_v2.c:103)
==1579== 
Error in realloc.
==1579== 
==1579== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1579==     in use at exit: 3,477 bytes in 9 blocks
==1579==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 3 frees, 8,717 bytes allocated
==1579== 
==1579== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1579==    definitely lost: 2,048 bytes in 1 blocks
==1579==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1579==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1579==    still reachable: 1,429 bytes in 8 blocks
==1579==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1579== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==1579== 
==1579== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1579== ERROR SUMMARY: 34 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

These errors point to the `realloc` line.

Comment: The first argument passed to function `realloc` must point either to memory address 0 (`NULL`), or to a memory segment previously allocated with either `malloc` or `realloc`. Are you sure that `tail->line_numbers` indeed points to one these options when you pass it to `realloc`?

Comment: @barakmanos See my answer. It's not the `realloc` that's causing the problem; it's that he's not using the pointer returned by `realloc`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using `realloc` correctly.

```
linenum_tmp = realloc(tail->line_numbers, ....
...
*(tail->line_numbers + counter - 1) = ...
```

If `realloc` needs to re-allocate your memory, the pointer you pass to it is `freed`. You then proceed to use the *old, freed* value of `tail->line_numbers`.

You must always use the *return value* of `realloc`.

I think what you want is:

```
tail->line_numbers = realloc(tail->line_numbers, ...
```

---

Secondly, you're misinterpreting what `valgrind` is telling you.

```
==1579== Invalid write of size 4
==1579==    at 0x40110E: process_input (rgpp_v2.c:181)
==1579==    by 0x400DCC: main (rgpp_v2.c:103)
==1579==  Address 0x51e0b9c is 1,020 bytes inside a block of size 1,024 free'd
==1579==    at 0x4C29B7E: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1579==    by 0x4010DD: process_input (rgpp_v2.c:177)
==1579==    by 0x400DCC: main (rgpp_v2.c:103)
```

What it's saying is: In function `process_input` (at line 181 of `rgpp_v2.c`), you're accessing memory that was previously `free`d. For your reference, it was previously freed was by `realloc`, which was called by `process_input` at line 177 of `rgpp_v2.c`.

Comment: On comp.lang.c, they like to bring up a corner case where realloc fails (returns NULL), but leaves the original data allocated. If you just overwrite the variable, then you've lost the data. (whether you can actually recover usefully without the extra space is another issue).

Comment: Wow, thank you. This works like a charm! The examples I've looked at used a temporary variable so I was confused. Forgive my horrendous ignorance, I was looking at the man page of realloc and it said that realloc returns a pointer to the newly allocated memory. So I thought a temporary variable was necessary.

Comment: I would definitely pay attention to what @luserdroog said in his comment, though. The point to remember is that if `realloc` returns a non-NULL value, the pointer you passed to it might have been `free`d, so you can't use it anymore.  You just forgot to assign your temporary variable back to the first pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
            if (counter == num_array_sz) { //Area of interest
                    num_array_sz *= 2;
                    if ((linenum_tmp = realloc(tail->line_numbers, sizeof(int) * num_array_sz)) == NULL) { 
                            exit_program("Error in realloc."); 
                    }
            }
            *(tail->line_numbers + counter - 1) = line_number;
```

You need to update your working variable with the result from `realloc`, something like this:

```
            if (counter == num_array_sz) { //Area of interest
                    num_array_sz *= 2;
                    if ((linenum_tmp = realloc(tail->line_numbers, sizeof(int) * num_array_sz)) == NULL) { 
                            exit_program("Error in realloc."); 
                    }
            }

            tail->line_numbers = linenum_tmp; // <---!

            *(tail->line_numbers + counter - 1) = line_number;
```